# How do the slapd logging levels work?

Tags: logging, openldap, rsyslog, slapd

I can't seem to find an example of how each of the log levels in slapd work. I want slapd to log the users who are logging in, and the server that they are trying to log into, as well as any authentication errors. I've tried using this LDIF to modify the logging level to every level (except for the debugging levels):

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: <log level>
```

Can someone point me to a more helpful resource than the OpenLDAP manual? Or give me explanation on what typs of information the logging levels produce?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting info into syslog, then it sounds like you're probably gonna need loglevel 256.  Which will log the initial connection to slapd, and assign it a connection number, for example "conn=7000", which you can use to reference all actions performed for that connection. The initial line will also include the IP from which the connection was made.

After that you'll have to parse looking for the UID specified, and the filters applied as far as groups and passwords are concerned.

As for troubleshooting the error codes, there are a number of lists for these codes, which will appear as "err=*" in the logs.  Here is one - https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes

Comment: While it probably solved OP's problem, this does not give any hints on how logging works and what to turn on for what kinds of messages.